# Wordpress blank page

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I moved this live website to my localhost. 
Whenever I try to access it through localhost I get this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYtka.png)

And thats not the only plugin.
There are like 3 others. I tried to disable the trouble causers, without success. 
This is what I got after. [A blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRibB.png)

Any ideas what could be causing this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

EDIT:
/wp-admin works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: It seems that this one file is completely missing. Probably the others too. Can you disable them by renaming the folder of the plugin that is causing errors? (not the wp-content/plugin) ... then go to the wp-config.php file and enable WP_DEBUG. this gives you much more information about errors.

It seems that the transfer of your files is incomplete.

Comment: that solved my issue @AdrianLambertz

Comment: Glad i could help! perfect! :-)

Comment: If you want you can make this an answer, I'll accept it asap. Good for your rep ;)

Comment: @AdrianLambertz

Comment: @Kevin.a done, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this one file is completely missing. Probably the others too. Can you disable them by renaming the folder of the plugin that is causing errors? (not the wp-content/plugin) ... then go to the wp-config.php file and enable WP_DEBUG. this gives you much more information about errors. It seems that the transfer of your files is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Enable wp debug from wp-config.php to know the cause.

To quickly resolve it, using FTP rename the plugins folder to plugins1 or something. This will give you access to your wp-admin for sure.

Comment: This fix should get you out of blank screen as well. Were you able to see errors on enabling debug?

Comment: WP debug mode true, right? i did that no luck tho still a blank page